# XML program not writing XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I've made a simple tool for generating an XML file. I have been using this tool over the last couple of days and no issues have arisen from it. Then yesterday I went to use it, and I'm getting the following error:

> XmlException: Document element did not appear. file:///C:/DarkRideSettings/DarkrideSettings.xml Line 1, position 1.

From my understanding, this error is saying that the computer cannot find the XML file in the stated location within the code. The thing is, I literally used this code the day before and the XML file is where it should be.

My code for writing my XML is as follows:

```
  public void WriteXMLFile()
{
    // location of the file
    string _filePath = "C:\\DarkRideSettings\\DarkrideSettings.xml";
    XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    // if the file exists
    if (File.Exists(_filePath))
    {
        // load it in
        _xmlDoc.Load(_filePath);
        // clear out the previous data
        _xmlDoc.RemoveAll();

        // create the main root node
        XmlNode rootNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Settings");
        _xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        // corners node (next layer down)
        XmlElement _cornerNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Screen_Corners");
        _xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(_cornerNode);

        #region Top Left Corners XYZ Values

        // indent top left corner value to screen corners
        XmlElement _topLeftNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Top_Left");
        _cornerNode.AppendChild(_topLeftNode);

        // set the XYZ of the top left values
        XmlElement _topLeftXNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("TopLeftX");

        // take string value and convert to float for use in final calculation
        float _topLeftXFloat = Convert.ToSingle(_screenWidthString);
        float _topLeftX = -_topLeftXFloat / 2.0f;
        _topLeftXNode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(_topLeftX);

        XmlElement _topLeftYNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("TopLeftY");
        _topLeftYNode.InnerText = _screenHeightString;

        XmlElement _topLeftZNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("TopLeftZ");
        float _topLeftZFloat = Convert.ToSingle(_distanceFromScreenString);
        float _topLeftZ = _topLeftZFloat / 2.0f;
        _topLeftZNode.InnerText = Convert.ToString(_topLeftZ);

        // indent these values to the top_left value in XML
        _topLeftNode.AppendChild(_topLeftXNode);
        _topLeftNode.AppendChild(_topLeftYNode);
        _topLeftNode.AppendChild(_topLeftZNode);

        #endregion

        _xmlDoc.Save(_filePath);

    }
}
```

This code would happily generate my XML file (please note, I've omitted some bits of code from this method to save on space, nothing of any major importance).

Can anyone see if I'm missing something from my code that I should have (I honestly have no idea, as I said, it worked fine yesterday!) or how I can defeat this error. My XML file is to be found at its required location and, even if it wasn't, my code should still write a new one!

Please help me.

Comment: Post your xml, I'm guessing you lack a <?xml version="1.0"?> in the beginning

Comment: Your code *only* writes the file *if* it already exists. Your `Save` call is within the `if (...)` block. That isn't the cause of your problem, but it *is* a problem. Given that you're just overwriting the file, why do you care whether or not it existed before? Why are you loading it at all?

Answer (score 1):

You do not use root element that you have created first, after you have create it, you are using `_xmlDoc`, replace yours `_xmlDoc` with `rootNode` and I assume everything will work.

```
 XmlNode rootNode = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Settings");
```

Comment: It looks fine to me - he's appending to the document element, *after* appending the root node to the document directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's the content of the file that seems to be the issue.

Check that you have the `xml root element` at the top of the file. It should look something like

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Comment: Ah, I do not have that. Is there a way to automatically add that in through my code?

Comment: by using XDocument for instance.

Comment: This shouldn't be *necessary* at all. XML declarations are optional.